# React Navigation clearInterval not working

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, expo, react-navigation-stack

React Navigation stack clearInterval not working

App.js Example

```
const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {
    screen: Home,
  },
  Contact: {
    screen: Contact,
  }
});
```

Home.js Example

```
componentDidMount() {
   this.interval = setInterval(this.load, 10000);
}
componentWillUnMount(){
   clearInterval(this.interval);
}
```

interval still works when I switch from home to contact.
Help me please.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, as @ABDELKHALEK said, the component will not be unmounted when navigating to another screen. What you need to do is use react-navigation [events](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/) to clear the interval:

```js
  componentDidMount() {
   this.interval = setInterval(this.load, 10000);

   // This will clear interval when navigating between screens
   this._unsubscribe = navigation.addListener('blur', () => {
      clearInterval(this.interval)
   });
  }
  
  componentWillUnMount(){
   // call this function to clean navigation listener when unmounting component
   this._unsubscribe();
  }
```

Bear in mind that if you want to run the interval every time user focus this component you will also need to use `focus` event.

Answer (score -1):

Actually I don't think that navigation to another screen will unmount the component.

So what I suggest is do the following when navigating to Contact Screen:

```js
import { StackActions, NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
    
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Contact' })],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: i have multiple screens